# Set default Apache page away from /usr/local/apache/htdocs

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

Installed Centos Web Panel on my server. All is well but when going to the IP address it displays the standard Apache page, it is served from `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` tried changing the location of this folder in: `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and restarting the server doesn't seem to have any effect. The server is shared IP address, and I want it to serve one of the domains instead.

In the file I changed:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/home/mydomain/public_html"
```

And

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/home/mydomain/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: You asked two questions, how to change documentroot and how to serve just one specific domain. You should create two seperated questions for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it turned out that at the bottom of the `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` there was an include `Include /usr/local/apache/conf/sharedip.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName xx.xx.xx.x
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Changing the `DocumentRoot` in the file and restarting had the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The directive you are searching for is `DocumentRoot`, you can find it in the virtual-host (there are multiple hosts per apache installation) config files.

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/apache-tips-moving-the-default-docroot-for-apache-on-centos-6/).